# How to restrict/obfuscate MySQL value when querying

Tags: mysql, api, obfuscation

So I'm building a bit of an API where users can query my database with read-only access.  However, I want to block certain fields, specifically IP addresses.  I'm currently using `preg_replace` in PHP to match and switch out IPs, but I feel like someone could get around that with come clever string-splitting MySQL functions.

Is there a way I can block/replace/obfuscate this particular field for this read-only MySQL user?

The record would be at (table.field):

```
`TrafficIp`.`Value`
```

An example query they might use would be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Hits, Value IpAddress
FROM TrafficIp
INNER JOIN Traffic
ON Traffic.IpId = TrafficIp.Id
GROUP BY Value
ORDER BY Hits DESC
```

How would I bait and switch?

Comment: Why can't you have your api just not serve it?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that you have an actual MySQL user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [create a *view* of your table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) that omits the field with the IP address, and let API users query that view, but not the underlying table.

Really, instead of trying to do "damage control" on the back end of the query, your API should be filtering the queries *before* they ever make it to the database. It is highly inadvisable to just pass through raw SQL queries from the outside world, into your database.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I would filter such a query to determine if it's going to return a "black-listed" entry?

Comment: One way to do that is to define a restricted query syntax that you carefully verify before passing it on to the database. However, even that is dangerous if you consider IP addresses secret: If you provide access to the IP address field and let external users query against it (but not return the actual IP address value in the select), an attacker could still derive IP addresses from your database query results using a few dozen queries. "Does anything start with 1?" No. "Does anything start with 2?" Yes. Does anything start with 20?" No. "Does anything start with 21?" Yes. And so on.